# How can I efficiently get multiple models that are referring to the current type?

Tags: django, django-models

One of our pages is painfully slow, because we are grabbing similar things relating to one thing. The models look different from each other but all relate to this container:

```
class MyItem(models.Model):
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    whitelabel = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    belongs_in = models.ForeignKey(Container)

class AnotherItem(models.Model):
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    belongs_in = models.ForeignKey(Container)
    starts = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow())

class ZomgItem(models.Model):
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    belongs_in = models.ForeignKey(Container)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

With a container like this:

```
class Container(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_stuff():
        things = list( MyItem.objects.filter(
            belongs_in=self, deleted = False))
        things.extend( AnotherItem.objects.filter(
            belongs_in=self, deleted = False))
        things.extend( ZomgItem.objects.filter(
            belongs_in=self, deleted = False))

        return things
```

The actual use case even messier of course. How can I make this stop being painfully slow?

Comment: You can use `itertools.chain` instead of extending the list, but I don't think it will give you noticiable speed-up: it will still be 4 db queries. So (if you are sure this is your bottleneck) you should use other optimizations like caching or changing you DB schema.

Comment: do you call get_stuff multiple times in the page? can't you move the deleted model instances in different model classes? eg DeletedZomgItem(ZomgItem):  deleted = models.BooleanField(default=True) ?

Comment: @Sammyrulez It was mostly to indicate that I'm performing a query on the Models. Like I could check `AnotherItem.objects.filter(created__lt=datetime.utcnow())` I rather not create one model for every state a model can be in.

Comment: @DrTyrsa I could cache the page which I will at some point, but right now I've got 350DB queries to generate one of my pages and want to get the worst case down. I'm fine with changing the DBSchema, though I'm not sure in what way.

Comment: JohnnyCache is a great solution too.

Comment: @KitSunde If you call `get_stuff()` only once, it's only 4 queries. I'm not sure it's a place where you should start optimization.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you say how do you use the "get_stuff" result after calling it. Maybe it's just a matter of making the more appropriate query...